# Big optional chunks in regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression

```
url\=\"(?P<url>((.*)))\"\s+exceptions\=\"(?P<exceptions>([^\"]*))\"\s+error\=\"(?P<error>([^\"]*))\"(\s+reputation\=\"(?P<reputation_opt>([^\"]*)))?\s+category\=\"(?P<category>([^\"]*))\"\s+reputation\=\"(?P<reputation>([^\']*))\"\s+categoryname\=\"(?P<categoryname>([^\"]*))\"(\s+content-type\=\"(?P<content_type>([^\"]*))\")?
```

However sometimes everything after capturing `url\=\"(?P<url>((.*)))\"` in my log file it can be sometimes optional so I decided to add`(...)?` around everything after `url\=\"(?P<url>((.*)))\"`. However this isn't doing what I want it to do. I want to capture the whole log when it does and doesn't contain everything after `url...`.

Here is my Regex with `()?` surrounding the optional chunk

```
url\=\"(?P<url>((.*)))\"(\s+exceptions\=\"(?P<exceptions>([^\"]*))\"\s+error\=\"(?P<error>([^\"]*))\"(\s+reputation\=\"(?P<reputation_opt>([^\"]*)))?\s+category\=\"(?P<category>([^\"]*))\"\s+reputation\=\"(?P<reputation>([^\']*))\"\s+categoryname\=\"(?P<categoryname>([^\"]*))\"(\s+content-type\=\"(?P<content_type>([^\"]*))\")?)?
```

Here is a part of the sample log entry I am interested in:

```
url="http://media.fastclick.net/w/get.media?sid=15971&tp=5&d=j&t=n" exceptions="" error="" category="178" reputation="unverified" categoryname="Internet Services" content-type="application/x-javascript"
```

Comment: What does the source look like?

Comment: Can you turn it into (somewhat) valid xml by any chance?

Comment: @PeeHaa no sorry =/ My specific job is to make one big regular expression to parse log files

Comment: Ow so your job is not finding the most sane solution for a problem?

Comment: @PeeHaa unfortunately not

Comment: Those regular expressions are completely unreadable. Break them up into multiple lines and add comments using [the `X` flag](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.X) when compiling them.

Comment: What do you want your output to look like, given the input in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was missing was `?` inside `url\=\"(?P<url>((.*)))\"`

Here is the answer

`url\=\"(?P<url>((.*?)))\"`

The ? helps make `.*` non greedy

Comment: Thre're absolutly no needs to have 3 capture groups (*a fortiori* the same) when only one would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make all groups optionnal, I remove the unecessary capture groups and escaped character:

```
(?x)   # to allow line break, comments in the regex
url=\"(?P<url>.*)\"
(?:\s+exceptions=\"(?P<exceptions>[^\"]*)\")?
(?:\s+error=\"(?P<error>[^\"]*)\")?
(?:\s+reputation=\"(?P<reputation_opt>[^\"]*))?
(?:\s+category=\"(?P<category>[^\"]*)\")?
(?:\s+reputation=\"(?P<reputation>[^\"]*)\")?
(?:\s+categoryname=\"(?P<categoryname>[^\"]*)\")?
(?:\s+content-type=\"(?P<content_type>[^\"]*)\")?
```

Comment: I thought about making the all the groups optional as well but I think  the answer I submitted would be a bit faster. take a look and correct my if I'm wrong. I just learned regular expressions not too long ago

Comment: @Liondancer: The more capture groups you have, the less fast you are.